# Prevent creation of sticky notes

Tags: stickynotes

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  How can I disable the Sticky Notes function so that I never, ever see them again?  I don't know what triggers their creation, since I never intentionally created any of them.

How can I determine what is causing them to appear?

Answer (score 0):

If 'Notes' appears after every re-boot, it is probably being run as a 'Session and Startup' Autostart Application.    Uncheck or Remove 'Notes' from the autostart file list.

MX Linux 18.3, ChaletOS 14.04 systems

Comment: So where is the autostart file list?

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  The startup list from System Settings shows only Dropbox.  So where is that autostart file list that presumably contains Notes?